# How do I insert auto increment ID immediately into another table after I inserted values in the main table?

Tags: mysql

I got two table `tbl_client` with a column `clientID` as PK (auto increment), `lname` and `tbl_served` with a column `servedID` as PK (auto increment) `clientID`.

When I insert values on `tbl_client`, the auto incremented ID will be inserted into `tbl_served`. Is it possible?

I tried using `set @id = select . . .` but its not working.

Comment: Do you mean you want a `trigger` to do it for you or want to do it manually?

Comment: if manually, `set @thatLastThing=LAST_INSERT_ID();`  ... use it in your next `INSERT` . Check out the manual sometime. [link for one page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html) . It's fun reading. Check it out :p

Comment: @Drew sorry and thank you.. solved it :))

Comment: maybe self-answer and accept. Share that knowledge.